# Display JSON as template list in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

I have following JSON document:

```
{
  "document": {
    "section1": {
      "item1": "Item1Value",
      "item2": "Item2Value"
    },
    "section2": {
      "item1": "Item1Value",
      "item2": "Item2Value"
    },
    "section3": {
      "item1": "Item1Value",
      "item2": "Item2Value"
    }
  }
}
```

Which I want to display in my django template. This document will be dynamic, so I want to display each sections dynamically. I am passing parsed (by json.loads()) string to the template.

I tried something like:

```
{% for section in json.document %}
    <div class="section">
        <h4><a href="#" class="section_toggle"></a>  {{ section|title }}:</h4>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            {% for field in json.document.section %}
                {{ field }} {# <---- THIS should print item1, item2... Instead, its printing "section1" letter by letter etc #}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't printting section's items properly. Any help?

Comment: Your Json format is off. The `document` values need to be a list for your code (atleast in theory) to work.

Comment: Is this actually a JSON string, or is it a dict? Show where you're getting it from and how you're passing it to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead pass the dictionary to your template and access it by iterating over the values using `dict.items` in your template.

```
{% for key1,value1 in json.document.items %}
    <div class="section">
        <h4><a href="#" class="section_toggle"></a>  {{ key1|title }}:</h4>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            {% for key2,value2 in value1.items %}
                {{ key2 }} 
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

In your code above, it was printing `"section1"` letter by letter because you were not iterating over the values of the `section1` key but on the `section1` string itself. If you need to access the items in a dictionary, you need to use individual variables for keys and values and use `dict.items`.

For example, the below code would print the keys and values of the `data` dictionary in the template.

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```